# Run a function on each query string value

Tags: php, arrays, query-string

I have a query string that looks like this.. `dinnerPlate=white&lunchPlate=purple&cup=black`

I also have an array that holds all of the available colors that can be allowed..

```
$availableColors = array("white","black","red","blue","green","pink");
```

What I need to do is populate an `img`'s `src` with the correct color from the query string. For example..

```
<img src="<?php echo $color['dinnerPlate']; ?>.png" class="dinnerPlate" /> 
<img src="<?php echo $color['lunchPlate']; ?>.png" class="lunchPlate" />
<img src="<?php echo $color['cup']; ?>.png" class="cup" />
```

What I need help with is creating a `php` function that can check each one of the query string values against the `availableColors` array to make sure its an available color. I don't want to have somebody manually type "yellow" into the query string because then I'll get a broken image. So if somebody types "yellow" into the query string the function would change yellow to something like `nocolor`. The function also needs to provide a way to output the color value of a specific item, like `echo $color['lunchPlate']`.

Thanks for any guidance!!

Comment: http://php.net/in_array

Comment: Yeah I know of that function. My problem is wrapping all of this stuff into one function so I can output it into my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to break up the query string by `&`, then by `=`. Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
$str = 'dinnerPlate=white&lunchPlate=purple&cup=black';

$availableColors = array('white','black','red','blue','green','pink');
$defaultColor = 'nocolor';

foreach (explode('&', $str) as $val)
{
    list($item, $color) = explode('=', $val);

    $color = in_array($color, $availableColors) ? $color : $defaultColor;

    $data[$item] = $color;
}
```

Then you simply get your items from the `$data` array.

Comment: This is awesome. Works almost flawlessly. How would I check to see if there's no value for one of the items? Right now if there's no value it does not get set to `nocolor`.

Comment: What does the query string look like?

Comment: Same as what I have in my question. However, in my actual page I have about 16 items to set colors on. So if I have an item that is not in the query string I'd like to set its color value to `nocolor` as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Please include a code example (something like pastebin).